# "ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new": How to directly initialize an template object with its own constructor as an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, new-operator

So my intention was to build a "Multibuffer" which has a definable amount of "SingleBuffers". The type that is stored is free, so I want to use templates for that reason. I am just playing around a bit.

But I don't know how to initialize the Singlebuffers in the Constructor of the Multibuffer directly.
I won't write down the complete classes, but the Constructors to show the problem. I defined the both classes in the header, as it should be done, when working with template classes.

So my Singlebuffer-Constructor looks like this:

```
  enum BufferState_E
  {
    BUFFER_WRITE = 0,
    BUFFER_READ,
    BUFFER_FORCED_READ // buffer is forced for reading
  };

  template<typename T>
  class SingleBuffer
  {
  public:
    /*
     * Constructor
     * constructs a Buffer with the concrete data field
     */
    SingleBuffer( unsigned int buffer_size )
    : entry_ptr_      ( new T[buffer_size]() ) //default constructor works?
    , end_entry_ptr_  ( &entry_ptr_[buffer_size-1] )
    {
      read_entry_ptr_   = &entry_ptr_[0];
      write_entry_ptr_   = &entry_ptr_[0];
      state_ = BUFFER_WRITE;
    }

  private:
    /* The pointer to the buffer */
    T * entry_ptr_;
    /* the pointers to the entry which is currently read/written */
    T *read_entry_ptr_;
    T *write_entry_ptr_;
    /* the pointer to the end of the buffer */
    T * end_entry_ptr_;
    /* The state of the buffer */
    BufferState_E state_;
  }
```

and my Multibuffer-Constructor which instantiates an amount of Singlebuffers (I wrote a comment after the problematic line of code):

```
template<typename T>
  class MultiBuffer : public BufferBase
  {
  public:

    MultiBuffer( unsigned int buffer_size = 2000 // size of one buffer
               , unsigned char number_of_buffers = 5 // how many buffers are there?
               , const char* name = "MultiBuffer"
               )
    : buffer_ptr_         ( new SingleBuffer<T>[number_of_buffers](buffer_size) ) // the problem line!
    , end_buffer_ptr_     ( &buffer_ptr_[number_of_buffers-1])
    , buffer_size_        ( buffer_size )
    , number_of_buffers_  ( number_of_buffers )
    {
      read_buffer_ptr_ = &buffer_ptr_[0];
      write_buffer_ptr_ = &buffer_ptr_[0];
    }  

  private:
    /* the normal buffer-pointer */
    SingleBuffer<T> *buffer_ptr_;
    /* the pointer to the end of the buffers */
    SingleBuffer<T> *end_buffer_ptr_;
    /* the pointer to the current read-buffer */
    SingleBuffer<T> *read_buffer_ptr_;
    /* the pointer to the current write-buffer */
    SingleBuffer<T> *write_buffer_ptr_;
    /* the buffer-size */
    unsigned int buffer_size_;
    /* the number of buffers */
    unsigned char number_of_buffers_;
  }
```

So my Compiler always tells me: "ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new" in the marked line of code. Looking up the cpp-reference for "new" doesn't really help, neither do the other asked questions that have to do with templates. 
If I just use the default constructor, like you see in the Singlebuffer initialization it seems to work but as soon as I want to pass a value to the constructor of my own defined template-class it crashes. I did manage to force it to build when not initializing in the Multibuffer-Constructor directly but with a loop which iterates the "number of buffers" and allocates memory in every iteration, but that's not how it should work, besides I don't really know if that really works error-free.

And I don't want to use std::-functions, because I'm working on an embedded system. The compiler is a GCC 4.8.1 and is not changeable too, and lambda-expressions are not supported too...

I hope there will be a possibility. Thanks so far.

Comment: Please ponder the **minimal** and **complete** aspects of an [mcve].

Comment: An embedded system that supports `new` should support `std::vector` just fine.

Comment: ok, I deleted an unneccessary inheritance and added the BufferState_E-enum. I hope this is ok now. It compiles exactly to the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it: You can't provide initialisation in `new[]`. You will have to assign to those objects later, probably in the body of `MultiBuffer::MultiBuffer`.

But you shouldn't do that. You should just use `std::vector` for your dynamic array needs. Your compiler provides it, and the library writers know what they are doing. "Standard library functions are bloated" hasn't been true *this century*